# chart does not change the values when the variable changes the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I was trying to update the data in a chart, using Chart.js, by clicking a button, but the chart does not change according to the data.
Another point is that if I do not declare a value for the variable "adata" the graph is not generated, even though I stated that the value of the date would be based on one of the selection values.

I'm trying to do everything without any server side programming (limited resources).

To make sure that the value of the variable "adata" changes when I select one of the options, I put a field in the

tag to display on the screen which the value of "adata"

Can you help me with what I'm doing wrong?
follow link to the variable "adata" with set value:   `<https://jsfiddle.net/DJacob/ndq6msuz/2/>`
and one with value-based selection:`<https://jsfiddle.net/DJacob/ndq6msuz/>`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `onchange` doesn't trigger (internal Jsfiddle problem). If you copy your code to your HTML it works without errors, but not updates graph.

You need to change data before calling `update()`:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = adata;
myChart.data.datasets[0].data = adata;
myChart.update();
```

I changed your jsfiddle to listen another change event, but you don't need to if you doing this locally (not jsfiddle):

https://jsfiddle.net/ndq6msuz/3/

Comment: thank you, it worked, I was several days trying to solve, thank you

Comment: and sorry for my bad english